# How to use self signed certificate to encrypt data post transmission?

Tags: ssl, encryption, passwords, self-signed

I am using a self signed certificate primarily to encrypt data over network. The question is, does SSL support encryption post transmission? How to achieve this?
I have the following options for encryption of credentials:
1. SSL implementation within the server
2. USing database default (MD5) encryption technique to store passwords

The problem with using the second approach is that there is no way to decrypt the passwords once encrypted
I need to decrypt the passwords occasionally in my use case. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Security related questions without programming should be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the certificate's public key and use RSA/OAEP to encrypt any kind of data that can be converted to binary. Using an SSL certificate for anything else than SSL encryption/authentication is usually considered bad practice though. If you require asymmetric encryption, generate a specific key pair for it.